# Disable printing of fonts/packages to STDOUT

Tags: warnings

Is it possible to disable most of the boilerplate information that is output to STDOUT, like package and font paths? For example some Unix commands have "verbose" or "quiet" command line options that allow you to adjust how much information gets written to STDOUT.

It is very common that I will miss important warnings because they get buried in all this other information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `--interaction=batchmode` suppresses all the output about style files loaded etc, but also things like warnings about overfull and underfull boxes. More severe warnings are still printed though.

Batchmode interaction also means that it won't stop for user input on error though.

Comment: Thanks, that is useful to know in general.  Unfortunately, overfull box warnings are exactly the ones that tend to get buried.