# Disable printing of fonts/packages during compilation - from the compiled file

Tags: compiling, warnings, logging

I just read this:

[Disable printing of fonts/packages to STDOUT](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44477/5640)

and I was wondering whether the same could be effected somehow from the .tex file being compile (probably you would want to do this before the `\documentclass`, or at least before all of the `\usepackage`s).

Comment: Does [Where to find official (!) and extended documentation for tex/latex's commandline options (especially -interaction modes)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91592/) help? So `\batchmode` before `\documentclass` will suppress everything except the initial banner.

Comment: Or you could use something like `arara`.